# Azure Sentinel's Kusto: How to do regex does NOT match?

Tags: azure, kql, kusto-explorer, azure-sentinel

Simplified example

| summarize event_count() by State
| where State matches regex "K.*S"
| where event_count > 10
| project State, event_count

OUTPUT:
State | event_count

---

KANSAS | 3166
ARKANSAS | 1028
LAKE SUPERIOR | 34

In the above example, a search is performed and output is restricted to when the regex matches. Instead, I would like to be able to exclude any events where the regex matches. In the above example, this would equate to returning all events that don't match "K.*S". Documentation shows "contains" & "!contains" as well as "has" & "!has"...but I am unable to find a "!matches regex" to the match regex operator. How do I exclude events from a search where a regex matches? In other words, how do I return events where the regex did not match. This would help me filter out any false-positive alerts from my rules.

I have tried using !contains operator and !has operator, but when the regular expression is overly complicated, I have not found a solid work around to excluding outside of a regex. My goal is to filter out any events from my search that match a regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`not` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/notfunction).

You should also move the filter to before the `summarize` statement

Answer (score 0):

Let me visualize the query based on Yoni's answer:

`| summarize event_count() by State | where event_count > 10 and not(State matches regex "K.*S") | project State, event_count`